# The function overriding is not working

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

A question about inheritance and function overriding.

```
// base.h
class Base {
protected:
    void a();
public:
    void b();
}

// base.cc
void Base::a() {
    // Empty.
    return;
}

void Base::b() {
    this->a();
}

// derived.h
class Derived : public Base {
protected:
    void a();
}

// derived.cc
void Derived::a() {std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;}
```

So in my program it's `Derived* p = new Derived()`, but `p->b()` doesn't print `OK`? Sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: `override` for `a` in Derived class would produce an error pointing the problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

You must declare a function `virtual` in order to make inheritance work.

```
// base.h
class Base {
protected:
    void a();
public:
    virtual void b();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to to mark `b()` `virtual` in the base class declaration:

```
class Base {
protected:
    void a();
public:
    virtual void b();
};
```

And note the semicolon at the end of the class declaration: this is required in C++. Note that you don't need to write `virtual` in the derived classes, although some folk adopt that style.

(Polymorphism is not automatic in C++, unlike Java).